# Higher Order Derivatives problem involving the position of a particle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, word-problem

> Given the position of a particle is $$s(t)=t^3-12t^2+36t-20$$
>
> a. Find the velocity and acceleration functions
>
> b. When is the particle moving to the right?
>
> c. When is the particle speeding up?

Here is my work. I am particularly concerned with parts b and c of this question. **Have I solved this correctly?**

[image]

Note that my answer for part c. should read 'when $t>4$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part $a$ looks good!
For part $b$ you must get two intervals. See if you can use below hint
$$ab \gt 0 \implies (a\gt 0 \text{ and }  b\gt 0) \text{ or }  (\color{blue}{a\lt 0 \text{ and }  b\lt 0})$$

Comment: So my full answer should be "when t>6 and t>2"?

Comment: Careful, $$\color{blue}{t-6\lt 0 \text{ and } t-2\lt 0}$$ gives you $$\color{blue}{t\lt 6 \text{ and } t\lt 2}$$

Comment: Why did you write t-6<0? Shouldn't it be positive, or greater than zero for the particle to move to the right?

Comment: Exactly! You want $(t-6)(t-2)$ to be positive. When is it positive ? It will be positive when both factors are positive. Also it will be positive when both factors are negative. Yes ?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now. Because even if t is greater than 2, the first term could still be negative. Okay! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thats it! It helps to look at the graph of quadratic $f(t) = (t-6)(t-2)$. The graph stays above x axis before and after the x intercepts.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice.